# Using Validation on Jquery pop up login menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jquery pop up menu using bootstrap . It has some validation issues like when password field is empty or  password is wrong ,I tried couple of ways . It works but when i type something in password or username field , the still stays there
Here are my codes

```
<div class="container">
    <h4>Demo Page</h4>
    <!-- twitter content -->
    <div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <div>
            <form class="contact" action="">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                        <li class="nav-header">Username</li>
                        <li>
                            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="txtUsername" name="username">
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-header">Password</li>
                        <li>
                            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="txtPassword" name="password">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <%--<input type="button" value="Sign Up" id="btnLogin" />--%>
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnLogin">
                Sign Up
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        </div>
        <div id="dialog" title="Message">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my js file has this function

```
function GetUserInfo() {
    var username = document.getElementById('txtUsername').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('txtPassword').value;           
    if (username == "") {
        $('#dialog').text("Please type a username.");
        return false;
    }
    else if (password == "") {
        $('#dialog').text("Please type a password.");
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "webservices/ProdMonitorService.asmx/ValidateUser",
        data: "{'username':'" + username + "','password':'" + password + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
            try {
                if (obj.length == 1) {
                    $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                }
                else {
                    $('#dialog').text(result.d.Message);
                    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I want to display the error message for when username or password not match and/or blank . 
i use this one  `<div id="dialog" title="Message">`  to display the error messages based on the condition.  The issue is , the error message not going away when you correct it

Any help appreciate..

Comment: can you format your code, remove the unnecessary parts, and clarify the problem you are having?

Comment: Where are you checking to see if the input fields change? You need to monitor if the value changes then remove the error message

Comment: And is the only problem that the error message doesnt go away when the user clicks in the input again to change their response?

Comment: Yes. First , when i leave it blank and click submit it shows error message , but when i type a username and click submit button , it still shows error message for username . it should show for password field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code in the beginning of GetUserInfo function.

```
$('#dialog').text("");
$("#dialog").dialog("close");
```

For validating username and password, you can achieve it from service side and return the status and message to the success result.

Hope it helps.

Thanks